# How to do a RavenDb Query index result as Include to document

Tags: include, indexing, ravendb

Both of the following queries work as expected. I'm having trouble figuring out how to return both from the database in one pull using the "Include()" method.

```
var result = _documentsSession
    .Advanced
    .LuceneQuery<MessageStatisticResult, MessageSummaryByUserIndex>()
    .Where("Email:" + command.UserName);

var user = _documentSession
    .Load<IUser>("users/" + command.UserName);
```

A soon as I add the "Include()" method both the Query() and Advance() are no longer relevant. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer was to delete my RavenDB code and reclone from git and rebuild. Then it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This also produces results but does not get both in one trip to the database:

```
var result = _documentsSession
    .Query<MessageStatisticResult, MessageSummaryByUserIndex>()
    .Customize(x => x.Include("users/" + command.UserName))
    .Where(x => x.Email == command.UserName)
    .FirstOrDefault();

var user = _documentSession
    .Load<IUser>("users/" + command.UserName);
```